# Unusual network activity is seen in Ubuntu's built-in System Monitor (14.04 LTS 64bit Spanish)

Tags: 14.04, networking, google-chrome, system-monitor

I detected some unusual networking activity on my PC. In System Monitor appears strange networking data-transfer, even when i close my web browser (Google Chrome 44.0.2403.130 64-bit) the activity continues, also i closed the any app that requiers or use internet conection, and the activty continues no matter what. Please note that i didn't found any strange process running background.

Also i run the next command in my terminal: `sudo netstat -ntp`

the terminal show the next text:

```
PID/Program name
```

tcp        0      0 192.168.0.4:51243       104.16.17.44:80         ESTABLECIDO 32051/chrome
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.4:58548       64.233.177.95:443       ESTABLECIDO 32051/chrome
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.4:38756       82.221.99.162:993       ESTABLECIDO 2190/python3
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.4:41953       192.111.0.25:443        ESTABLECIDO 32051/chrome
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.4:41900       192.111.0.25:443        ESTABLECIDO 32051/chrome
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.4:42433       74.125.21.188:5228      ESTABLECIDO 32051/chrome
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.4:41872       192.111.0.25:443        ESTABLECIDO 32051/chrome
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.4:52000       64.233.177.138:443      ESTABLECIDO 32051/chrome
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.4:41891       192.111.0.25:443        ESTABLECIDO 32051/chrome
tcp        1      0 192.168.0.4:40842       91.189.89.144:80        CLOSE_WAIT  2160/ubuntu-geoip-p
tcp6       1      0 ::1:52325               ::1:631                 CLOSE_WAIT  1041/cups-browsed

"ESTABLECIDO" is the spanish word of established.

any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

P.D: My English is not very good.

Comment: do you ever use a printer?

Comment: @mchid Yeah i use a printer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you might be able to do here is to go into your chrome settings, scroll down and click on **advanced settings**.

Scroll down and under **system**, untick the box for **continue running background apps when google chrome is closed**.

---

One looks like [vivaldi mail](https://mail.vivaldi.net/webmail/) (python3).

Google chrome looks to be connected to websites stackexchange or askubuntu, google, etc.

Ubuntugeoip I believe is the timeserver

and cups is for your local printer.

Comment: The setting "continue running background apps when google chrome is closed" is disabled. I forgot say that i use a printer.

Comment: @edr-01 I included some more info on the IPs listed. You can put most of these addresses into a browser and you will get the website or something related. Additionally, you can use the `whois` command to look these up as well. To install, just run `sudo apt-get install whois`.

Comment: I found nothing out of usual, looks like the data transfer is caused by my local printer and there's nothing to worry about, thanks.

Comment: it's good to stay vigilant